# Reed Solomon - why the interest in original view decoders?

Tags: error-correcting-codes

As seem in the history section of the Wiki Reed Solomon article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction#History

Efficient decoders for BCH / fixed generator polynomial based code words were developed back in 1969 - Berlekamp Massey decoder, and 1975 - Sugiyama extended Euclid decoder.

However, decoders based on Reed Solomon's original scheme of using variable polynomials based on the message, using a fixed set of values mapped by that polynomial to create a code word were developed years later, such as 1986 - Berlekamp Welch decoder, and 2002 Gao extended Euclid decoder.

The Berlekamp Welch decoder is the slowest since it uses Gaussian elimination which is O(n^3). Sugiyama and Gao decoders use extended Euclid algorithm, and both are O(n^2), but Gao is significantly slower, 3 to 16 times slower depending on N and K for a RS(N,K) code in my testing.

Other than research purposes, was there a reason for going back the original encoding scheme despite being relatively slower?

There is one slight advantage, the original scheme maximum code word size can be one element larger than the BCH scheme maximum code word size.